# Validation Issue in html field

Tags: magento2

I am using the UI component form with some additional attribute field using an HTML template. But I am not able to validate these field as par standard. required property is not working.

Example:

```
 <section class="admin__page-section price-lab attribute-lab-3">   
            <label class="attr-label" for="nego">Nego </label> 
            <select  required   data-form-part="merchandising_builder_form" name="nego[]" class="negolist " id="nego" multiple size="8"     
                    data-bind="options: negoOptions, 
         optionsText: 'value', optionsValue: 'id'  ">

            </select>   
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add data-validate binding like below ;

```
 <section class="admin__page-section price-lab attribute-lab-3">   
            <label class="attr-label" for="nego">Nego </label> 
            <select  required   data-form-part="merchandising_builder_form" name="nego[]" class="negolist " id="nego" multiple size="8"     
                    data-bind="options: negoOptions, 
         optionsText: 'value', optionsValue: 'id'  " data-validate="{required:true}">
            </select>   
        </section>
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, thanks for replying I tried but it is not working.

Comment: Hi All, Now it's working in with jquery validation. i have added class class="required-entry"